# JNA set pointer to Boolean

Tags: pointers, jna, setvalue, native-methods

How is possible to set a pointer to a boolean value? For long I use:

```
Pointer pointer = new Memory (size);
pointer.setLong(0, longValue);
```

`pointer.setBoolean(...)` is not defined, so for boolean I tray to use a setInt but not wrok.

Comment: boolean is not a C type.  figure out what size data type your library uses to represent boolean values and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Use IntByReference .

```
  IntByReference ref = new IntByReference();
   /*Pass ref as argument to some function*/
  if(ref.getValue() == 0)
     ...
  else
     ...
```